# Making recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-apps-script

I'd like to make an object likes

obj = {2 : {3 : {4 : { } } } }

```
function tsttt (){
  var tstObj = {};
  var cntr = 0;    //counter
  var key = [2,3,4];   ///keys array what I want to put in object

  function re(obj){
    var k = key[cntr];
    if(cntr == 2){
      return obj;
    }else if(!(k in obj)){
      obj[k] = {};
    }
    cntr++;
    return re(obj[k]);
  }
  var rslt = re(tstObj);
  Logger.log(rslt); //google apps script log
}
```

it returns now empty object  {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning the very last object you created, or the property assigned to "3". If you want it to return the full object then have it return tstObj.

```
  function re(obj){
    var k = key[cntr];
    if(cntr == 2){
      return tstObj;
    }else if(!(k in obj)){
      obj[k] = {};
    }
    cntr++;
    return re(obj[k]);
  }
```